# Where is the video my sister sent to me on iMessage? I clicked save and can't find it

Tags: iphone, video, ios, messages

I have an iPhone 3GS.  I just did the software update to iOS5.  My sister took a cute video of my kid and sent it to me on iMessage.  I tried to save it to my phone so I could upload it to the computer and/or facebook, and now I can't find it.  It is not in my camera roll or in my iCloud.

So the question is....where is the file and why can't i find it?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check in your 'Videos' app; it should be saved in there.

Comment: just checked.  Its no there.  any other suggestions?